# update post meta on function.php does not work

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to update post meta when the post saved.

I like to have **published date** into custom field named '2a' only once when it is saved.  No update of '2a' by modifying post.

This is code I added on function.php.  It does not afect anything on custom field.  Is there any wrong on my code?

When I ver_dump it, it returns correct value I expected.  However, it does not update post meta...

```
function add_custom_field( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
if ( is_single() && metadata_exists( 'post', $post_id, '2a' ) ) :{
    $date = get_post_meta( $post_id, '2a', true );
    update_post_meta($post_id, '2a', $date );}
    else:{
    $date = get_the_date('Y-m-d', $post_id);    
     return update_metadata('post', $post_id, '2a', $date,); 
    }
endif;
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'add_custom_field', 10, 3 );
```

I found even this simple code does not work... why

```
function update_custom_field( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    $date = get_the_date('Y-m-d', $post_id);    
    update_post_meta($post_id, '2a', $date);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_custom_field', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Check here - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  get post meta, and trigger if certain meta empty is one of methods for this goal, but I prefer metadata exists if possible.  Thanks anyway.